# OpenMP Fortran Default Clause

Tags: fortran, openmp

This parallel works fine.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL Private(irep)
!$OMP DO
do irep = 1, nrep
  print *, "Using thread: ", omp_get_thread_num(), "irep: ", irep
end do
!$OMP END DO NOWAIT
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

This works fine too.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP DO
do irep = 1, nrep
  print *, "Using thread: ", omp_get_thread_num(), "irep: ", irep
end do
!$OMP END DO NOWAIT
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Why does it return nothing when I use Default clause?

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(Private)
!$OMP DO
do irep = 1, nrep
  print *, "Using thread: ", omp_get_thread_num(), "irep: ", irep
end do
!$OMP END DO NOWAIT
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's just take a look at a simpler case:

```
program testprivate
use omp_lib

integer :: nrep
nrep=16

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(Private)
print *, "Thread: ", omp_get_thread_num(), "sees nrep = ", nrep
!$OMP END PARALLEL

end program testprivate
```

We run this and get:

```
$ gfortran -o private private.f90 -fopenmp
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
$ ./private
 Thread:            3 sees nrep =            0
 Thread:            0 sees nrep =            0
 Thread:            1 sees nrep =        32581
 Thread:            7 sees nrep =            0
 Thread:            4 sees nrep =            0
 Thread:            5 sees nrep =            0
 Thread:            2 sees nrep =            0
 Thread:            6 sees nrep =            0
```

[OpenMP private variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#PRIVATE), whether private by default or otherwise, are undefined on entering the private section.   That doesn't matter for the loop index, `irep`, which is set in the do loop; but if (say) your compiler is setting each thread's `nrep` to zero inside the private section then the loop will never execute.  Worse, each thread could have different values for nrep and anything could happen.

So you don't want `nrep` to be `private`.   You could still have `default(private) shared(nrep)`, or even `firstprivate(nrep)`, although there's no advantage here to having each thread have its own `nrep`.